# Checking for data types in statements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a better way to check for multiple variables in an `if` statement JavaScript?

```
num2 = 23;
num1 = 3;

if(typeof num1 === 'number' && typeof num2 === 'number'){
    
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you doing you need to check the types, might be better solution....

Answer (score 6):

You might make a function that checks if every one of its arguments is of the desired type:

```
const isType = (type, ...args) => args.every(arg => typeof arg === type);
if (isType('number', num1, num2)) {

}
```